# Material components mat-button and mat-icon alignment

Tags: html, css, angular-material

The material components are nice but confusing for customization.
Can you please advise on how to align both horizontally and vertically a *mat-icon* inside a *mat-button*?

This HTML:

```
  <button mat-button
         class="closeX-btn">    
    <mat-icon class="closeX-icon">  
      clear</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

and this SCSS:

```
.closeX-btn {
  border: thin solid orange;
}

.closeX-icon {
  font-weight: bold;
  height:18px;
  width:18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size:18px;
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

produces this:

[image]

A change of SCSS of the button to:

```
.closeX-btn {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border: thin solid orange;
}
```

produces this:

[image]

And if we change: *mat-button* to: *mat-icon-button*:

```
  <button mat-icon-button
         class="closeX-btn">    
    <mat-icon class="closeX-icon">  
      clear</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

We get this:

[image]

**The desired outcome is**:

- the button border is exactly around the icon,
- in other words, the orange border is right around the red border
- while, always matching the size of the icon - no margins, no padding, (no space around)

For *mat-button* like this:

[image]

and for *mat-icon-button* like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with the same lack of documentation and ambiguity in material design customization here is what I resolved so far.

This code brings us closer for *mat-icon-button* like this:

HTML:


clear

SCSS:

```
$closeX-icon-size: 18px;

.closeX-btn {
  height:      $closeX-icon-size + 6px;
  width:       $closeX-icon-size + 6px;
  line-height: $closeX-icon-size + 6px;
  border: thin solid orange;
}


.closeX-icon {
  height:      $closeX-icon-size;
  width:       $closeX-icon-size;
  line-height: $closeX-icon-size;
  font-size:   $closeX-icon-size;
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

- resulting in this:

[image]

Please note, that the icon is still not fully in the middle but slightly shifted below the center, which is well apparent , ...

... if we change: *mat-icon-button* just to: *mat-button* while keeping all else the same , we get:

[image]

where obviously the width has no impact. This remains to be resolved and the correct answers are hopefully to come ...

Obvious is, that we cannot rely on consistency among related material components such as the *mat-button*  and  *mat-icon-button*